# Import JS to HTML 404

Tags: javascript, python, html, import

[image]
Could someone help me figure out why this import is not working? Even when I do script/import.js it will not work. I am getting this error message: 127.0.0.1 - - [09/Sep/2020 15:09:35] "GET /import.js HTTP/1.1" 404. Given the file structure in attached image... what am I missing :D

Comment: import.js seems to be under another project

Answer (score 0):

You want to access a file located on a folder who is located in the folder one level up from the current folder, so you should do this :

```
<script src="../script/import.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you are using Flask for your app, in which case you will need to serve your javascript files as 'static' files, see: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/static/

Move your 'script' folder into a new folder called 'static', then change your script import to:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='script/import.js') }}"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much... its always the silliest things. Completely forgot I was going through flask!